# how to use .Values.load on .Values.envtype.name.something in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

i want to call values on helm charts like this
i want to use the value of the key .Values.load, on .Values.envType.name,

name will be .load so we want to use it like this in a dynamic way so we can just change .Values.load and it will use it on other values.

I hope i explained myself well :)

EDIT:

values file structure

```
LOAD: DCS
EnvType:
  DCS:
    name: DCS
    NORMAL:
      limitRange:
        limits:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: 0.5
    HEAVY:
      limitRange:
        limits:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: 0.5
  DEV:
    name: DEV
    NORMAL:
      limitRange:
        limits:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: 0.5
    HEAVY:
      limitRange:
        limits:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: 0.5
```

so basically i want to access any of the values inside the EnvType object with the load key
so it can be more dyanmic.

Comment: Can you give a clearer example of what the values file structure would look like, how you'd use the `load` key, and what code you've written already?  For other similar questions I've endorsed using the `helm install -f` option, which would let the administrator inject additional (environment-specific) values files at deployment time without changing your Helm template code at all; would this approach work for you?

Comment: @DavidMaze I’ve added to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Helm does not support secondary rendering, but you can use [yaml anchor](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/) to achieve this function.

values.yaml

```yaml
LOAD: &LOAD DCS
EnvType:
  DCS:
    name: *LOAD
    NORMAL:
      limitRange:
        limits:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: 0.5
    HEAVY:
      limitRange:
        limits:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: 0.5
  DEV:
    name: *LOAD
    NORMAL:
      limitRange:
        limits:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: 0.5
    HEAVY:
      limitRange:
        limits:
          memory: 256Mi
          cpu: 0.5
```

templates/cm.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "test.fullname" . }}
data:
  load: {{ $.Values.LOAD }}
  enntype: |-
  {{- toYaml $.Values.EnvType | nindent 4 }}
```

cmd

```bash
helm install test .
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  enntype: |-
    DCS:
      HEAVY:
        limitRange:
          limits:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 256Mi
      NORMAL:
        limitRange:
          limits:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 256Mi
      name: DCS
    DEV:
      HEAVY:
        limitRange:
          limits:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 256Mi
      NORMAL:
        limitRange:
          limits:
            cpu: 0.5
            memory: 256Mi
      name: DCS
  load: DCS
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: test
  namespace: default
```

Comment: actually what i'm trying to do is to access the limitRange.limits to create a LimitRange dynamically, do you know how to do it with this yaml anchor ?

Comment: Could you give a clearer example ? values.yaml , expect output, templates ...

Comment: Well i decided that it is too complicated to deal with in one values file.
what do you think about separate it to 2 values files ?
making it a delivery of three values files.
values.yaml env.yaml data,yaml (example names)